Unexpected behaviour of TextField using Observation @Observable with MVVM implementing regex validation
Updating value of an Observable view model inside it doesn't reflect the updated value on TextField in the view
I am creating a simple signup flow using SwiftUI and I am exhausted already. I am unable to achieve expected results from Observation @Observable implementing MVVM architecture to work with TextField. I have a ParentView that holds multiple child views like- NameView, PhoneView, EmailView. ParentView holds its ViewModel which is injected in it's child views. "Child views don't have their own View Models"

What I expect:

I am trying to have regex validations for respective TextFields preventing input of certain characters. I think all the logic should be held in ViewModel so by implementing the new Observation framework, I am able to achieve many things (helpful) but not when it comes to instant two way communication between view and viewmodel using that same property especially in case of TextField.

What's happening:

When I type anything in the TextField, the view model property willSet/didSet closure invokes and I can perform the operation. When I called the validation function from this closure, on console I get the right value but it doesn't reflect on the TextField. However, if I add a certain delay of 0.01 seconds for example, it updates the UI but still that deletion of character is sometimes visible and that's a sign of bad UX.

Child View

struct NameView: View {

   @State var viewModel: ParentView.ViewModel
   @FocusState var focusedField: ViewsTextField?

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         TextField("", text: $viewModel.name, prompt: Text("Full Name"))
         .foregroundColor(Color.black)
         .focused($focusedField, equals: .name)
      }
   }
}


View Model

extension ParentView {
   @MainActor
   @Observable
   final class ViewModel: BaseViewModel {
      
      var focusedField: ViewsTextField?
      var name = "" {
         didSet {
            print("Name: \(name)")
            validateNameTextField(newValue: name)
         }
      }
      
      func validateNameTextField(newValue: String) {
         let allowedCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
         let filtered = newValue.filter { allowedCharacters.contains($0) }
         if filtered != newValue {
            self.name = filtered // This doesn't work but if I add a minimum delay of even 0.1 seconds enclosing in main queue then it works but this ruins the user experience as the deletion of character is visible on UI
         }
      }
   }
   
   enum ViewsTextField: Hashable {
      case name, phone, email
   }
}

Is this the expected behaviour or I am not supposed to use Observable like this? I want to understand the right approach to my problem.

You'll need to learn the View structs and state/binding for your view data. Using view model objects won't work. Observable is for model data not view data.
